# Preventing Redirect to main page when clicking skip-link using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

The problem I am facing is that because of a  tag in my html layout, I am being redirected to the main landing page when clicking a "skip to main content" link.

I am using the following JQuery to prevent this behavior, but it also prevents the direction to main content.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#skip-link').click(function () {
        $("#" + $(this).attr("href").slice(1) + "").focus()
        alert("link Skipped")
        event.preventDefault() 
    });
});
```

My question is, how can I prevent the redirection to the relative address, without using prevent Default.

Comment: why you dont want to use `event.preventDefault`?

Comment: Can you hardcode one of the behaviors? e.g. `if (nextLink !== 'something') { event.preventDefault() }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#skip-link').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#" + $(this).attr("href").slice(1) + "").focus();
        alert("link Skipped");
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

Ok if I understood you correctly, this is what you want, simply:

```
<a href="#skip-link">Jump to main</a>
<a name="skip-link"></a><div class="row" id="anchor">blabla</div>
```

or jQuery:

```
<a id="skip-link" href="#anchor">Jump to main</a>
<div class="row" id="anchor">blabla</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#skip-link').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var hash = $(this).attr("href").slice(1);
        alert(hash);
        $("#" + hash).focus();
        $("#" + hash).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/75k7u4w3/

Comment: I attempted the method you provided, but it did not work for me. I will try again, with a revised anchor tag and see if that helps.

Comment: @Joshua Pearson if you want to actually go to that anchor, you should use `click()` instead of `focus()` - `$("#" + $(this).attr("href").slice(1) + "").click();`

Comment: I attempted with the click function and no success. The issue is originating from redirection of a relative link due to base href = "/"

Comment: @Joshua Pearson can you provide the actual link you are trying to slice()?

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct but I am providing the HTML link and the anchor it is attached to   
Main skip link
<div>
    <a id="skip-link" href="#anchor">Skip To Main Content</a>
</div>
Anchor Destination
<div class="row" id="anchor">

Comment: @Joshua Pearson ok by default when you click on `Skip To Main Content` you will jump to `<a name="anchor"></a><div class="row" id="anchor2">` - is that what are you trying to achieve? P.S. note that gave different `id` for second `div`

Comment: I believe that is correct. I am targeting the anchor link for accessibility. The problem is that it is forcing a Nav event instead of directing to the anchor.

Comment: That method did not work either.  the expected behavior is this https:///Home#anchor but what is being returned is this https:///#anchor

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it  is working now.